# Does SPIED CoreNLP support languages other than English?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I don't know Java at all so I'm struggling a bit to figure out whether SPIED could work with languages other than English.
I've tried substituting default models.jar with Spanish specific models.jar and overriding default props with Spanish specific props. 
Still, `edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass` seems to be using English specific annotators.

The command executed was:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.9.2.jar:stanford-spanish-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar:javax.json.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass -props patterns/example.properties
```

Where `example.properties` contains the properties for the Spanish model (as in the default Spanish properties file) as well as the properties for the patterns module.

That didn't work. Is there any straightforward way to apply patterns module to other languages?